# OBIEE 12.2.1.0 Missing Tools in analytics dashboard

Tags: oracle, obiee

i'm trying to get familiar with Oracle OBIEE and stumbled upon some weird issues with it's functionalities.

In my domain I'm missing some of the components which were supposed to be installed. There are even some links in the Administration tab of OBIEE for these missing Components but they result in 404 Errors.

[Missing Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz5QK.png)

There should at least be 3 more components available:
   - Data Exploration & Discovery
   - Mobile Application
   - Published Reporting

I tried looking it up but couldn't find a solution yet. Does anyone have some hints were i could continue my search?

Comment: What environment are you using? One you've installed yourself? Best place to learn more about OBIEE is [SampleApp](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/obiee-samples-167534.html)

Comment: I actually have 2 environments. One i've installed myself on windows server 2012 r2 (local vm), where everything works as intended. And the one where components are missing is running on linux which i have access to via putty/winscp.

The oracle installation on linux wasn't done by me, i'm not really used to linux as i mostly work on windows.

Comment: Not much to add here I'm afraid. Sounds like an environment-specific issue related to the install. You know on Linux you can't run Admin Tool etc - it's not that you're expecting to find it there?